# To list digits in a number. Name error in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Name error in a small program, I am trying to list the digits in a number, no clue why its throwing name error.

```
def print_digits(n):
    l1 = 1
    l2 = 1

while(n!=0):
    l1 = n%10
    print(l1)
    
    l2 = int(n/10)
    n = l2
    
def main():
    n=int(input())
    print_digits(n)
    
main()
```

To list digits in a number. It throws a name error.

```
 Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    while(n!=0):
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Comment: while loop execute before main function and in that `n` is not defined. while  loop is not in print_digits function

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you haven't indented your while loop. As it's not indented, it's being run as the file is read by the interpreter, and you wont have defined `n` yet.

See below for the correct indentation:

```py
def print_digits(n):
    l1 = 1
    l2 = 1

    while(n!=0):
        l1 = n%10
        print(l1)
    
        l2 = int(n/10)
        n = l2
    
def main():
    n=int(input())
    print_digits(n)
    
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question was already provided by HPringles. Here is an example of how to solve the underlying issue to print all digits in a number in a more elegant way:

```
# Replace with your desired number
n = 1337

# Convert the number to a string so we can iterate over each digit
n_str = str(n)

# Iterate over each digit in the string and print it
for digit in n_str:
    print(digit)
```

Comment: Although this is a correct method for printing the digits, the question is asking how to fix the NameError they're getting.

Comment: I agree, but the solution to the naming error was already answered in your commit. Therefore, this just should have been a more elegant way to solve the underlying issue. Regardless, I agree with you that I should have stated that better.

Comment: Apologies if I came across harsh there, it wasn't intended :)

Answer (score 0):

Python follows indentation unlike other languages. End of any statement in python has to be indented. While block needs to be indented, error is occurring because python treating it as independent statement. Align while block inside. Copy the below code and run it. Added some one simple improvement to inut.

```html
def print_digits(n):
    l1 = 1
    l2 = 1
    while(n!=0):
        l1 = n%10
        print(l1)
        l2 = int(n/10)
        n = l2
    
def main():
    n=int(input("Please enter the number more than 2 digits here: "))
    print_digits(n)
    
main()
```